# Cálculo de data errado

Tags: c#, .net, data

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
TimeSpan dt = dataFinal.Subtract(dataInicial);

double anos = Math.Floor(dt.Days / 365.25);
double meses = Math.Floor(((dt.Days - anos * 365.25) / 30));

return string.Format("{0} Anos e {1} mês(es)", anos, meses);
```

Ele recebe uma data e calcula o tempo entre as duas datas. Porém se eu passar por exemplo:

```
DataIncial -> 11/03/1992
dataFinal -> 11/03/2015
```

ele deveria me retornar `23 anos e 0 mes(es)`, mas esta retornando `22 anos e 12 mes(es)`.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Não vejo nada de erro, os dois resultados se equivalem (23 anos e 0 meses é igual a 22 anos e 12 meses). Acho que é apenas uma questão de formatação da saída do resultado.

Comment: Deve se usar a propriedade TotalDays

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternativamente pode usar uma biblioteca que saiba lidar com isto de forma adequada como a [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) do Jon Skeet (eu queria que ela se tornasse oficial do .NET). Ele já deu um exemplo fazendo isto [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862695/221800):

```
var start = new LocalDateTime(2014, 1, 1, 8, 30);
var end = new LocalDateTime(2014, 9, 16, 12, 0);
Period delay = new PeriodBuilder { 
        Months = 8, 
        Days = 10,
        Hours = 2,
        Minutes = 20
    }
    .Build();
Period difference = (Period.Between(start, end) - delay).Normalize();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DifferencePeriod.cs).

Porque esta alternativa é boa? Porque ela pensou em tudo. A maneira que está sendo feita na pergunta é ingênua e desconsidera, por exemplo, que os meses tem quantidade de dias diferentes e anos bissexto da forma correta (mesmo que pareça que está). Se quer uma solução real e não aproximada, então faça da maneira correta. Na forma atual vários momentos darão resultados errados, apesar que a maioria possa acertar. Mas é coincidência. Como se costuma dizer: até um relógio parado marcará a hora certa duas vezes por dia.

É possível escrever código próprio para lidar com isto mas não é o foco da pergunta e provavelmente eu esqueceria de algum ponto e o algoritmo não seria confiável.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode corrigir isso com uma verificação da variável `meses` antes de imprimir.

```
if(meses == 12) {
  meses = 0;
  anos++;
}

return string.Format("{0} Anos e {1} mês(es)", anos, meses);
```

Comment: Estava escrevendo uma resposta igual a sua. Como já postou, vou deixar apenas a sua.